# How to show the facets with 0 count in sxa checklist filter component

Tags: sxa, search-facet

I have multiple filters on my page which includes Location, distance and 2 Checklist filter(with multiple selection). Initially page is loaded with no filters selected and result is read from the scope defined. The checklist filter is displayed with counts. 
[image]

When i select the options from bedroom filter the other filter also gets updated and loads only the facets with counts

[image]

**I want to show the other facet value as well when the count is 0.** 
I did the below setting to show the facets with 0 count but it doesnt seems to work

[image]

**SXA version 1.8.1
Sitecore version 9.0.2**

Answer (score 1):

The `Minimum Number of Items` setting that you've used is the correct one. I'm currently in the process of setting up the same filter (but only with single select) in the exact same version of Sitecore and SXA that you are using and currently it looks like this:

[image]

Have you double checked that everything is published to the `Web` DB properly?

In our case we had the filter on a `partial design` located in a base site. I've seen some issues where the result was cached and I really had to publish the base site (including the `partial/page design`), all the `datasources`, settings and the site where the page was located. I even ended up doing an `IIS` reset to make sure all caches where cleared.

Comment: i was able to achieve to show the facet with 0 count but on my local environment. When i deploy on server it doesnt work. The only difference i have is in local i am using solr search and in dev i am using azure search. Could this be the issue ?

Comment: We are using Solr throughout all of our environments, so I'm not sure if it could be related to Azure Search. I do suggest to pick 1 search provider for all environments. With a setup like that you'll never know where the issue is coming from. Also Solr and Azure Search do not completely support the same parts in the query. For a search provider strategy I recommend reading https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10161/what-are-the-available-methods-for-local-development-when-using-azure-search-in