# SXA checklist filter doesnt return facets with count 0 when used with azure search

Tags: sxa, azure-search

I am currently using `Sitecore version 9.0.2` and `SXA version 1.8.1`

**Requirement : -** 
In checklist filter, I want to show all the facets irrespective of the results.
If for a facet the result is not there it should still show with count 0.

I was able to achieve all this in my local environment, but when I deploy the same thing on the server it doesn't work. If a facet has 0 results it doesn't show up in the filter.
Have posted the question before also [HERE](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19083/how-to-show-the-facets-with-0-count-in-sxa-checklist-filter-component)

The only difference in my local and server environment is the search index used
Local I am using Solr and on a server it's azure.

**Is it like azure doesnt return facets if the count is 0 ?**

**On Local environment with solr search**
[image]

**On server with azure search**
[image]